# JavaScriptSerializer issues

Tags: c#

SO I am getting a response from the google translate API's like this:

```
"{\"responseData\": {\"translatedText\":\"Hola Mi nombre es\"}, \"responseDetails\": null, \"responseStatus\": 200}"
```

My code looks like:

```
 private string getText(string response)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver());
        translationReturnObject obj = serializer.Deserialize<translationReturnObject>(response);

        return obj.translatedText;
    }
```

with translationReturnObject defined like this:

```
[DataContract]
class translationReturnObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "responseData")]
    public string repsonseData { get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "translatedText")]
    public string translatedText { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "responseDetails")]
    public string responseDetails { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "responseStatus")]
    public string responseStatus { get; set; }  

}
```

My problem is that translatedText is not getting deserialized correctly. No matter what the language being returned is (so I don't think it is an Encoding issue) the value is null.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is wierd about it? not sure what you are getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the JSON that's returning, you'll see that `translatedText` is a *property* of `responseData`. Therefore, you'll need the following:

```
public class TranslationResponseData
{
    public string translatedText { get; set; }
}

public class TranslationReturnObject
{
    public TranslationResponseData repsonseData { get; set;}
    public string responseDetails { get; set; }
    public string responseStatus { get; set; }  
}
```

**EDIT**: Also, you don't need to worry about `DataContract`/`DataMember`. `JavaScriptSerializer` will map the JSON name to the public property name.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed the issue and your fix worked. Sorry if it seemed like a n00b mistake but in json I am a n00b.

Comment: @Alex - No worries. You just have to be extra careful when analyzing the JSON especially if *you* didn't create it.

Comment: In this case he doesn't have to worry about the datacontract and datamember, but if he wanted to rename some properties for serialization or exclude some, he would need it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `JavaScriptSerializer` works with the DataContract and DataMember attributes. Have you tried using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) class?

The JavaScriptSerializer works off the property name itself. It was deprecated but was resurrected for MVC for some reason. DataContractSerializer was released with WCF.

Comment: Actually it does work, it may not be needed as CloudlessSky pointed out, but it is just fine with all the other stuff. Of course, I have removed it now to make it more readable since it isn't needed. I got as far as I did by another stackoverflow answer and that was how they did so I thought it necessary.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky I thought it was in 3.5 and then undeprecated in 3.5 SP1 See here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx scott mentions it in the comments. I had tried to use it with DataMembers initially and it totally ignored them. Maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Wow, good catch! I never even noticed that it was. That was very dumb of them to deprecate it. Glad it's still with the framework!